# Error: Internal server error laravel ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Please help me  I am getting error "Internal server error"
 This is PostController.php in larvae

I am using ajax to save the post in database.

I also pasted javascript code so that some me can suggest the proper solution

```
public function create(Request $request)
        {
            if ($request->isMethod('get'))
            return view('posts.form');

            $rules = [
              'title' => 'required',
              'description' => 'required',
            ];

            $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
            if ($validator->fails())
            return response()->json([
              'fail' =>true,
              'errors' => $validator->errors()
            ]);

            $post = new Post();
            $post->title = $request->title;
            $post->description = $request->description;
            $post->save();

            return response()->json([
              'fail' => false,
              'redirect_url' => url('posts')
            ]);
        }
```

---------------java script code--------

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form#frm', function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
var form = $(this);
var data = new FormData($(this)[0]);
var url = form.attr("action");
$.ajax({
type: form.attr('method'),
url: url,
data: data,
cache: false,
contentType: false,
processData: false,
success: function (data) {
$('.is-invalid').removeClass('is-invalid');
if (data.fail) {
for (control in data.errors) {
$('#' + control).addClass('is-invalid');
$('#error-' + control).html(data.errors[control]);
}
} else {
ajaxLoad(data.redirect_url);
}
},
error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
alert("Error: " + data);
}
});
return false;
});
```

Comment: Share your log file content.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have error reporting on ? If not you do it as below

1. Go to environment file of your project(.env)
2. Change below constant as stated

   APP_DEBUG=true
3. Now send Ajax request once again it will show exact what error causing the internal server error , Check that line/function/file.

There will be syntax error or some logical coding error which causing the Ajax request internal server error.

Comment: APP_DEBUG=true is true in .env file.

Comment: So you should able to see the error which is throwing while your server side code is running , Check it in request response